# How to setup daily Notification in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, android-alarms

I want to set daily Notification(Alarm) at `10 AM` daily. What to edit in following code to set it at `10 AM` ?
Also how to make it run in background to raise the Alarm?

Here is the java code of main activity:

```
package com.rufflez.tenksteps;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        int i = preferences.getInt("numberoflaunches", 1);

        if (i < 2){
           alarmMethod();
            i++;
            editor.putInt("numberoflaunches", i);
            editor.commit();
        }

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            splashMethod();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void alarmMethod(){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this , NotifyService.class);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, pendingIntent);



        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void splashMethod(){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new SplashScreenFragment()).commit();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                        .commit();
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            WebView webView = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("http://inwhizz.com/");
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webView.setInitialScale(50);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public static class SplashScreenFragment extends Fragment {

        public SplashScreenFragment() {
        }

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState){
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.splashscreen, container, false);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is code of notify service:

```
public class NotifyService extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationManager mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent1, 0);

        Notification mNotify = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Log Steps!")
                .setContentText("Log your steps for today")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setSound(sound)
                .addAction(0, "Load Website", pIntent)
                .build();

        mNM.notify(1, mNotify);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I too am struggling with the AlarmManager right now... fortunately, I think I may have an answer to one part of your Q, though...

> calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);

into

> calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, **10**);
>   Blockquote

... and probably removing "calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);" should take care of firing it daily at 10am.

I happened to read somewhere that we are required to use a "PendingIntent created by a getService()" redirecting your work to an IntentService that does its work in the background. I hope this helps, at least, in pointing the search in the right direction!

Good luck!